How to enable access to my local hard disk (from browsers) after it was unintentionally denied?
I wanted to open a locally created .html file.  A dialog was presented asking me to allow or deny access to the file.  Apparently navigation within dialogs via the Tab is not working on my macos presently: when I tried to do it and hit enter I ended up hitting Deny .
Now I'm stuck with this:  how can I get a chance to choose "Allow" again?

As an aside: I do have Keyboard navigation enabled.  I might ask a separate question on why it does not work


Open the Privacy and Security panel in System Settings, select the Files and Folders sub-panel, find Google Chrome in the list of applications, and give it access to the Downloads folder.
